# Formgroup issue in subscribe: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using ionic & angular.
The fields name are coming from a _httpClient.get call.
Therefore to be able to set the FormGroup, I put the set up in the subscribe.

Then the console complains about 
**NewOrderPage.html:28 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

Here is the piece of code :

```js
export class NewOrderPage {
  ...
  validations_form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
      ...
      public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    ...
    this.drinks = personService.getAllDrinks();

    this.drinks.subscribe((value) => {
      let ctrls = {};
      ctrls['amount'] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
      ctrls['date'] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
      ctrls['place'] = new FormControl(this.places[0], Validators.required);
      for (let c of value) {
        ctrls[`drk_${c.id}`] = new FormControl(false);
        ctrls[`drk_amt_${c.id}`] = new FormControl('');
      }
      this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group(ctrls);
    });
  }
}
```

UPDATED: HTML code:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>New Order</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding class="form-content" [fullscreen]="true">
    <ion-header collapse="condense">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="large">New Order</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  <form [formGroup]="validations_form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(validations_form.value)">    
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="slide">    
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Place</ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="place" interface="popover">
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of (places | async)" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Date</ion-label>    
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="date"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>             
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Amount</ion-label>    
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="amount"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>     
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="slide">      
          <ion-card>   
            <ion-card-title>Drinks</ion-card-title> 

            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (drinks | async)">
              <ion-label color="primary">{{item.name}} drk_{{item.id}}</ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="drk_{{item.id}}"></ion-checkbox>
              <ion-input type="text" formControlName="amount_{{item.id}}"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit">Save</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

I think it could be because of the formbuilder is defined in the subscribe and not available outside?...

Thanks for reading,

V

Comment: Where are you using the `get`? Post that too. Make sure that is called after the form creation.

Comment: Well nobody can tell what the problem is without seeing the related html/where its being used.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ramesh. The get is in the this.drinks = personService.getAllDrinks(); that you'll find at the top of my sample of code.

Comment: Thanks for reading @ukn, I edited my initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your formgroup first and then patch the values.
For dynamic controls use formarray and change the bindings in the html accordingly

```
this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
'amount': ['', Validators.required],
'place': [this.places[0], Validators.required]
'drks' : this.formBuilder.array([])
...
});

this.drinks.subscribe((value) => { 
  for (let c of value) {
    let drks = this.validations_form.get('drks') as FormArray;
    let drk = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [c.id],
      amount: [c.amount]
    });
    drks.push(drk);
  }
});
```

your template should be like this

```
<div formArrayName="drks"
  *ngFor="let item of validations_form.get('drks').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="id" />
    <input formControlName="amount" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nandha. Seems very close to the answer. 
in the formBuilder group I would like to have fields drk_"c.id" and amount_"c.id".

Comment: Based on your text I finally succeeded to fix my stuff like this:
    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'amount': ['', Validators.required],
      'date': ['', Validators.required],
      'place': [this.places[0], Validators.required]
      });
    this.drinks.subscribe((value) => { 
(1/2)

Comment: for (let c of value) {
        this.ShowDiv['amount_drk_' + c.id] = false;
        const control: FormControl = new FormControl("false", Validators.required);
        this.validations_form.addControl('drk_'+c.id, control); 
        const control2: FormControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
        this.validations_form.addControl('amount_drk_'+c.id, control2); 
          };});  (2/2)